# Android: Stop an intent and return to the main activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I have developed an application that somewhere has an image button.

```
ImageButton buttoncalllog = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    buttoncalllog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
            showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivity(showCallLog);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

This button, when its clicked it's open the contact list. The problem is that i cant return to my application! When i press the return button to my device, nothing happens... If i kill my application and open it again the first screen is again the contact list! 
I have to restart the device or reinstall the application!
Any help?

**EDIT :**

I removed the call to `finish()`, but still it's not going back when I press return. My updated code :

```
ImageButton buttoncalllog = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    buttoncalllog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
            showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivity(showCallLog);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `finish()` on your Activity after launching the `Intent`.

**[`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)** is used to kill an Activity and should be called only when you want to *finish* your Activity. Since you are killing your application after launching the Intent, there is nothing that the app can return to when you press the return button.

```
ImageButton buttoncalllog = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    buttoncalllog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            Intent showCallLog = new Intent();
            showCallLog.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            showCallLog.setType(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_TYPE);
            startActivity(showCallLog);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have removed the finish() call but nothing still happens when i press the return button.
I have updated my first post.

Comment: What are you doing in the Call log activity ? Simply hitting the `back button` should take you back to the previous activity. Are you selecting anything in the call log or something like that ?

Comment: And please have a look at your post and see how questions should be edited to update. You need to retain the original query and add the updates in the EDIT section. It helps in maintaining the integrity and validity of the answers posted.

Comment: Sorry for the edit. I tried my app to a different device and it works fine. The problem occurs to an old Samsung I5800. I will restart the device remove the app and check again...

Comment: Not a problem. It's understandable considering that you are new here. :)

Comment: I removed finish() and at least when i press the home button i go to home and when i resume the original app it works fine. Maybe is something wrong with my device. Thanks again for your time and your understanding for my noobity ;)

Comment: Oh, in that case, maybe your return button needs to be fixed, rather than your code. :P And you are welcome, most welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

fisrt don't call `finish`

in additionally  you should call `startActivityForResult` in order the receive the user select choice

read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) for more  info

Comment: I removed the finish() but still i cant return to my application... Also i don't need to read the selected contact from the contact list so the startActivity should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your manifest file? You might need to make sure you defined the parent activity for the application to go to. Check for `<meta-data android:value="com.example.parentactivity"` under your activity tag

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Activty Flag -

```
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
```

with that you can go back to your app activity